# jsp security constraint not working

Tags: jsp

Here is my web.xml

```
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Staff</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/staff/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
            <role-name>staff</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Registered Users</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/registeredUser/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
            <role-name>staff</role-name>
            <role-name>registeredUser</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

This is my index page, because I want them to login using the j_security_check

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <jsp:forward page="/registeredUser/SplashPage.jsp"/>
</head>
</html>
```

It will go directly to the page and never ask for a login.

My directory is roughly like this:

```
WebContent
index.jsp
WEB-INF
-->lib
-->views
   --->admin
      --->//admin pages
   --->staff
      --->//staff pages
   --->registeredUser
      --->registeredUser pages
```

Basically it will go straight to the pages without any j_security_check. If I make one of the constraints *.jsp it will go into the j_security_check. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security constraints are not applied on server-side forwarded requests, simply because it's too late anyway to restrict the access. Besides, the control is 100% in hands of the web developer, so the developer should by itself know good enough what s/he is doing. The security constraints are only applied on direct client-side requests. You need to send a redirect instead of a forward. A redirect instructs the client to send a brand new HTTP request on the given URL.

You can send a redirect by calling `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()` in a servlet filter, or by a HTML `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` element in the `<head>`, or by JSTL `<c:redirect>` tag.